# ListView divider line in Xamarin Android app (Visual Studio) is not visible

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

The ListView divider is not visible in my Android Xamarin app (Visual Studio). Unfortunately
[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310963/listview-divider-is-not-visible)
is not working.

Here is my theme.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="bg">#ffffff</color>
  <style name="MyTheme">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ff2f4453</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#ff527791</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#ff527791</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ffffffff</item>
    <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#B6B6B6</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1px</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/bg</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

and here the Main.xml from the activity with the ListView-Control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/usersList">
</ListView>
```

When i change the theme to one of the defaults, the divider is shown correctly, but when i use my own theme, it's no more visible.

Did i forgot something to add in the colors?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: can you try changing the value of `1px` to `1dp`??

Comment: Has no effect, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:dividerHeight="5dp"
```

Comment: can you expand your answer a bit, giving a bit of explanation of how and why that line of code will fix the problem?

Comment: I knew that,  I have another stackoverflow account, I asked a  question and that question was downvoted many time so,  I was not able  to ask or answer anything so, I made this new one.